# Getting Error: Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIDOMWindow.getComputedStyle]

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I have a bit of javascript code to find and replace text into an image. I then gather the font size of the original text and use that to set the size of the new image.

Problem is, I keep getting the error: `Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIDOMWindow.getComputedStyle]`

Code:

```
function findAndReplace(searchText, replacement, searchNode) {
    if (!searchText || typeof replacement === 'undefined') {
        // Throw error here if you want...
        return;
    }
    var regex = typeof searchText === 'string' ?
                new RegExp(searchText, 'g') : searchText,
        childNodes = (searchNode || $("body").get(0)).childNodes,
        excludes = 'html,head,style,title,link,meta,script,object,iframe';
        var cnLength = childNodes.length;
    while (cnLength--) {
        var currentNode = childNodes[cnLength];
        if (currentNode.nodeType === 1 &&
            (excludes + ',').indexOf(currentNode.nodeName.toLowerCase() + ',') === -1) {
            arguments.callee(searchText, replacement, currentNode);
        }
        if (currentNode.nodeType !== 3 || !regex.test(currentNode.data) ) {
            continue;
        }
        var parent = currentNode.parentNode;
        var frag = (function(){
                var html = currentNode.data.replace(regex, replacement);
                var wrap = document.createElement('div');
                var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
                wrap.innerHTML = html;
                while (wrap.firstChild) {
                    frag.appendChild(wrap.firstChild);
                }
                console.log(currentNode);
                var jQNode = $(currentNode);
                console.log("yay");
                // var fontSize = jQNode.css('font-size');
                if (!currentNode || currentNode == document) currentNode = document.body
                var fontSize = getStyle(currentNode, 'font-size');
                console.log("tast");
                var heightPixels = fontSizeToPixels(fontSize);
                $(".InLogo",frag).each(function(){
                    $(this).css("height", heightPixels+"px");
                });
                return frag;
            })();
        parent.insertBefore(frag, currentNode);
        parent.removeChild(currentNode);
    }
}
function getStyle(el,styleProp) {
  var camelize = function (str) {
    return str.replace(/\-(\w)/g, function(str, letter){
      return letter.toUpperCase();
    });
  };

  if (el.currentStyle) {
    return el.currentStyle[camelize(styleProp)];
  } else if (document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle) {
    return document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el,null)
                               .getPropertyValue(styleProp);
  } else {
    return el.style[camelize(styleProp)]; 
  }
}
```

The error occurs at this line `return document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el,null).getPropertyValue(styleProp);` of `getStyle()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something.childNodes includes textNodes as well as Elements, and that's a problem for the getStyle() function.

Nodes don't have a style (Elements do), so who knows what will happen when you feed getStyle something that has .data; a plain Node.

Check for the existence of style to avoid the run-time error:

FIX:

```
var fontSize =  currentNode.style ? getStyle(currentNode, 'font-size') : 0;
```

Comment: getStyle is in the question I posted at the bottom

Comment: snap, darn touchscreens; didn't see it. that is the issue, answer updated.